# About AngularJS pagination (I used localStorageService before but it wasn't the solution i wanted to apply)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, pagination, local-storage

First, Thank you for watching this question!

I'm newbie to angularJS and i'm trying to make pagination to be more flexible to use.

Below is my situation.

1. I made pagination function
2. It works as my intention
3. But, When i get into other page(leave list page which includes pagination function), and try to go back, the problem appears!
4. **(Here is what i want to solve) I go back to list page by clicking backspace key or clicking back button on view. and the params i entered in list page is gone!**

   - In multi page application, the url can be '/tt?aid=11&bid=22&cid=33', and i get into detail view page, and i can retrieve to '/tt?aid=11&bid=22&cid=33' by just clicking back button. but in angularjs, it goes back to list page with no params.

And below is what i tried to solve above problem.

- I used local-storage-service
- I used onPageUnload event(of browser)

Comment: You should use $stateparams instead of  above url structure.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Hi! first, thanks for your comment. I used stateParams before but i don't know how to store it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this best fits.

Store the page no. 
When you click back to get that list, feed that page no.
page no can be stored in a scope variable.

Your pagination function should be able to give the list based on page no.

Comment: Hi @Ujjwala Bollam! i think i can solve this problem and your idea helped me. Very thank you for reply. ^^